# Multipart form upload resumable?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, multipart

Can a Multipart upload be resumed from the offset at which the connection gets terminated?

I'm just curious if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but your code in the server must conform to the multipart pause and resume, so the code is complex in the server ,you should store vary part sizes during the upload, or do not know the size of the data in advance. The client firstly gets the uploaded size and then multipart upload the rest parts in your client code.

Comment: I am using a server that has some sort of support for it but someone implemented the iOS client upload functionality with AFNetworking's Multipart form upload stream and when the connection goes down it errors out on the client which cancels that upload to restart from the beginning when the connection to the web is reinstated.